# how will you handle the exception for overridden method

Tags: java

```
class Parent{

public void m1() Throws Exception{

         //m1
      }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    public void m1() {
   }
}
```

The above program compiles successfully. But how will we handle exception thrown by the overridden method, Since overridden method is not throwing any exception.

Comment: same as any other method that is not throwing an exception - since posted code is doing nothing, strictly speaking, there is no exception to handle - and we have no idea what this method is supposed to do and what exceptions are involved, nor we know anything about context (GUI, logging, ...).

Answer (score 3):

You must read about `checked` and `unchecked` exceptions & exception handling when overriding.

Basics rules are:

```
1. If SuperClass does not declare an exception, then the SubClass can only declare unchecked exceptions, but not the checked exceptions.

2. If SuperClass declares an exception, then the SubClass can only declare the child exceptions of the exception declared by the SuperClass, but not any other exception.

3. If SuperClass declares an exception, then the SubClass can declare without exception.
```

You can refer to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exception-handling-with-method-overriding-in-java/ for better understanding.